# AllenNLP 2.0: Using `allennlp predict` with MultiTaskDatasetReader leads to RuntimeError

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

I trained a multitask model using allennlp 2.0 and now want to predict on new examples using the `allennlp predict` command.

**Problem/Error:**
I am using the following command: `allennlp predict results/model.tar.gz new_instances.jsonl --include-package mtl_sd --predictor mtlsd_predictor --use-dataset-reader --dataset-reader-choice validation`

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/bin/allennlp", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(run())
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/__main__.py", line 34, in run
main(prog="allennlp")
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/__init__.py", line 119, in main
args.func(args)
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 220, in _predict
manager.run()
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 186, in run
for batch in lazy_groups_of(self._get_instance_data(), self._batch_size):
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/common/util.py", line 139, in lazy_groups_of
s = list(islice(iterator, group_size))
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 180, in _get_instance_data
yield from self._dataset_reader.read(self._input_file)
File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/data/dataset_readers/multitask.py", line 31, in read
raise RuntimeError("This class is not designed to be called like this")
RuntimeError: This class is not designed to be called like this
```

**As far as I understand, that's what's going on:**

This [RuntimeError is raised by the MultiTaskDatasetReader](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/d2ae540d489336ba05f15479d3c55530b0bd6949/allennlp/data/dataset_readers/multitask.py#L30) because the `read()`-method of the MultiTaskDatasetReader should not be called  itself. The `read()`-method should only be called for specific DatasetReaders in `MultiTaskDatasetReader.readers`.

The read()-method of the MultiTaskDatasetReader is called because in the jsonnet-config I have specified the DatasetsReaders as follows:

```json
"dataset_reader": {
    "type": "multitask",
    "readers": {
        "SemEval2016": {
            "type": "SemEval2016",
            "max_sequence_length": 509,
            "token_indexers": {
                "bert": {
                    "type": "pretrained_transformer",
                    "model_name": "bert-base-cased"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "type": "pretrained_transformer",
                "model_name": "bert-base-cased"
            }
        }, ...
    }
}
```

Usually the `type` of dataset_reader indicates the dataset-reader class to be instanciated for prediction. But in this case the `type` just points MultiTaskDatasetReader, which has no `read()`-method implemented and contains multiple DatasetReaders.

As far as I understand, when using `allennlp predict` I need to specify somehow which of the multiple DatasetReaders should be used.

**The questions is:**

How can I specify which specific DatasetReader (of the multiple DatasetReaders in `MultiTaskDatasetReader.readers`) should be used when executing `allennlp predict`? Or more generally: How can I get `allennlp predict` to run with a MultiTaskDatasetReader?

**Additional code, for the sake of completeness:**
The predictor:

```py
@Predictor.register('mtlsd_predictor')
class MTLSDPredictor(Predictor):

    def predict(self, sentence: str) -> JsonDict:
        return self.predict_json({'sentence': sentence})

    @overrides
    def _json_to_instance(self, json_dict: JsonDict) -> Instance:
        target = json_dict['text1']
        claim = json_dict['text2']
        return self._dataset_reader.text_to_instance(target, claim)
```

Comment: That seems like a serious issue. I put a GitHub issue at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/4973 and will look into this.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.

Comment: I put a fix here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/pull/4991
I'm not sure I have covered all the use cases though. Can you try it with that and let me know if that works?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the slow answer. I still get a NotImplementedError by _json_to_instance() at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/8fbc9728e99a85483b8a061b246c6547bab15e40/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py#L281. Tracing the error back:

Comment: Since I have no default predictor specified for each model-head (https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/8fbc9728e99a85483b8a061b246c6547bab15e40/allennlp/predictors/multitask.py#L51) I see that a "normal" Predictor is instanciated for each head at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/8fbc9728e99a85483b8a061b246c6547bab15e40/allennlp/predictors/multitask.py#L53. And then where the error occurs the _json_to_instance() is called - although it is not implemented for a "normal" predictor.

Comment: This raises the question for me: Can/Should I specify a default predictor for each model-head? If yes, how can I do that in the jsonnet-file?

Comment: The error message (also split in parts due to the char-limit): File ".../mtl_sd_venv/bin/allennlp", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/__main__.py", line 34, in run
    main(prog="allennlp")
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/commands/__init__.py", line 119, in main
    args.func(args)
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 239, in _predict
    manager.run()

Comment: File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 211, in run
    for model_input_json, result in zip(batch_json, self._predict_json(batch_json)):
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/commands/predict.py", line 157, in _predict_json
    results = [self._predictor.predict_json(batch_data[0])]
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py", line 54, in predict_json
    instance = self._json_to_instance(inputs)

Comment: File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/multitask.py", line 74, in _json_to_instance
    instance = predictor._json_to_instance(json_dict)
  File ".../mtl_sd_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py", line 287, in _json_to_instance
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Comment: Nevermind! I just had to set `default_predictor` as a class-attribute of the model-heads to `"mtlsd_predictor"`. Now it all works! Thank you!

Comment: Sweet! I will try to capture some of this in an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. One is a bug in AllenNLP that is fixed in version 2.1.0. The other one is that @sinaj was missing the `default_predictor` in his model head.